# Smarty foreach not showing data

Tags: php, smarty

I am new to smarty and I am trying to get my assigned variable `$dropcat` to work - I can `print_r` out this array fine.

When I use the following method nothing displays why?

```
{foreach  from=$dropcat item=cat}
      <select name="{$cat.id}" multiple>
        <option value="{$cat.id}">{$cat.name}</option>
      </select>
      {/foreach}
```

Comment: have you insert `$smarty_instance->assign('dropcat',$dropcat);` before display?

Comment: @chumkiu I have that line in my code not my .tpl

Comment: Yes. Your code seems correct. So the error should be elsewhere

Comment: @chumkiu is my syntax correct as the closing select is red?

Comment: I think that highlight syntax of Stackoverfloiw doesn't support smarty :) Your code has not syntax error... maybe logical error (now you got N select with only one option)

Comment: Does select tag will be outside of foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be something like:

## PHP

```
// other stuff, instance etc
print_r($dropcat);
$smarty->assign('dropcat',$dropcat);
$smarty->display('yourhtml.tpl');
```

## TPL

```
<select name="category" multiple>
{foreach from=$dropcat item='cat'}
   <option value="{$cat.id}">{$cat.name}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
```

Note foreach inside select and assign in php code.

If still nothing appear, try to clear smarty cache, or your other project cache if any.